# Probability question on winning lottery number combination

Tags: probability, proof-verification

In a state lottery, a player must choose $4$ of the numbers from $0$ to $9$. If all 10C4 outcomes are equally likely, what is the probability that a player has

(a) all $4$ of the numbers as those of the winning lottery? Answer: There is just one winning $4$ digit combination. So 1/(10C4)

(b) $3$ of the numbers of the winning lottery? Answer: (4C3*6)/10C4

(c) at least $1$ of the numbers? Answer: 1-P(no winning digits), i.e. 1-(6C4/10C4)

Please tell me whether the above answers are correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer to part (a) is correct.

For part (b), note that given a winning number (e.g. 5229), there are four ways a ticket could match three of the digits and not match in the remaining digit. There are 9 ways to mismatch a digit, so the number of ways to match 3 digits is $4\times9=36$. This makes for a probability of $\frac{36}{10^4}=\frac9{2500}$.

For part (c), the probability of matching no numbers can be calculated in a similar way as part (b) to be $\frac{9^4}{10^4}$, so the probability of matching at least one number is the complement of this, i.e. $1-\frac{9^4}{10^4}$ or $\frac{3439}{10000}$.

Answer (score 0):

The probability that you choose exactly $n$ correct numbers is:

$$\frac{\binom{4}{n}\cdot\binom{10-4}{4-n}}{\binom{10}{4}}$$

---

The probability that you choose at least $n$ correct numbers is:

$$\sum\limits_{k=n}^{4}\frac{\binom{4}{k}\cdot\binom{10-4}{4-k}}{\binom{10}{4}}$$

---

The probability that you choose at most $n$ correct numbers is:

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\frac{\binom{4}{k}\cdot\binom{10-4}{4-k}}{\binom{10}{4}}$$